# Data driven pages displaying same feature?

Tags: arcmap, data-driven-pages

I'm creating data driven pages that display specific roads within specific counties. For whatever reason, the same roads are displayed on multiple pages even though the the correct route id is shown. I've provided pictures to help clarify. As you can see, the same route is displayed, but the route id is correct. When I zoom to the feature in data view, it shows me the correct route.[image]

[image]

The process I used to create the data driven pages is as follows:

1. Add the polyline shapefile from the appropriate database connection.
2. Use "Select by Attributes" to identify specific roads.
3. Create layer from selected features.
4. Set up data driven pages
   [image]
5. Add inset map, title, north arrow, scale bar, legend, and page text.

Of the 90+ counties I've done, I've only had this issue with 6 of them. Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. When setting up data driven pages, under the Extent tab select "Center and Maintain Current Scale."